# Q.all doesnt resolve in correct order

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I'm having trouble with the execution order of Q's promises in Node.js.

The code is supposed to do the following:

a) Execute a query and use the resulting lat/lon pairs to

b) Calculate shortest paths (using an async function) and

c) Return them

```
  query() // Runs the query
    .then(function() {
      return computeRoutes(); // Calculates the routes
    })
    .then(function() {
      return returnRoutes(); // Returns the routes as JSON
    });
```

The problem is that while the coordinates[] array gets populated in query() and is filled/available in computeRoutes(), the routes[] array remains empty in returnRoutes().

The strange thing is that when I do not loop over coordinates[] in computeRoutes() but just compute one route for coordinates[0], the chain of promises succeeds (but ofcourse I see only one route returned as JSON)

Any ideas on what could be wrong here?

Thanks!!

Full code:

```
app.get('/',
function(req, res) {

  var id = parseInt(req.query.id);
  var radius = parseInt(req.query.radius) || 5000;
  var routes = [];
  var coordinates = [];

  function query() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    console.log('Starting query function...');
    var query = client.query('SELECT ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(a.geom, 3857),4326)) AS fromlat, ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(a.geom, 3857),4326)) AS fromlon, ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(b.geom, 3857),4326)) AS tolat, ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(b.geom, 3857),4326)) AS tolon FROM emme_veh AS c, emme_nodes3857 AS b, emme_nodes3857 AS a WHERE c.fid = a.id AND c.tid = b.id AND c.fid = $1 AND ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom) < $2', [id, radius], function(err, result) {
      console.log('Inside query. result.rows.length:',result.rows.length);

      for(var i in result.rows) {
        coordinates.push({'from':[result.rows[i].fromlon,result.rows[i].fromlat], 'to':[result.rows[i].tolon,result.rows[i].tolat]});
      }

      deferred.resolve();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  function computeRoutes() {
    var the_promises = [];

    for(var i in coordinates) {
      var deferred = Q.defer();

      var query = {coordinates: [coordinates[i].from, coordinates[i].to], alternateRoute: false}
      osrm.route(query, function(err, result) {
        if(err) return res.json({"error": err.message});
        // console.log(result.route_geometry);
        routes.push(result.route_geometry);
        deferred.resolve();
      });
      the_promises.push(deferred.promise);
    }
    return Q.all(the_promises);
  }

  function returnRoutes() {
    return res.json(routes);
  }

  query()
    .then(function() {
      return computeRoutes();
    })
    .then(function() {
      return returnRoutes();
    });

});
```

Comment: [Don't use `for in` enumeration on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Comment: You shouldn't use global `routes` and `coordinates` arrays. Instead, use the promise resolve values!

Comment: Ah, good advice on both points. I knew I was doing something backwards. For..in was the root cause of the problem. Using globals was unnecessary too. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer after some trial-n-error.

The problem was that I was generating the promises in the computeRoutes() function using a for..in loop.

Switching to a forEach loop with functions did the trick.

Working code snippet (look at the computeRoutes() section):

```
app.get('/',
function(req, res) {

  var id = parseInt(req.query.id);
  var radius = parseInt(req.query.radius) || 5000;
  var routes = [];
  var coordinates = [];

  function query() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    console.log('Starting query function...');
    var query = client.query('SELECT ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(a.geom, 3857),4326)) AS fromlat, ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(a.geom, 3857),4326)) AS fromlon, ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(b.geom, 3857),4326)) AS tolat, ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(b.geom, 3857),4326)) AS tolon FROM emme_veh AS c, emme_nodes3857 AS b, emme_nodes3857 AS a WHERE c.fid = a.id AND c.tid = b.id AND c.fid = $1 AND ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom) < $2', [id, radius], function(err, result) {
      console.log('Inside query. result.rows.length:',result.rows.length);

      for(var i in result.rows) {
        coordinates.push({'from':[result.rows[i].fromlon,result.rows[i].fromlat], 'to':[result.rows[i].tolon,result.rows[i].tolat]});
      }

      deferred.resolve();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  function computeRoutes() {
    var the_promises = [];

    console.log('Inside computeRoutes()');

    coordinates.forEach(function(coordinate) {
      var deferred = Q.defer();

      osrm.route({coordinates: [coordinate.from, coordinate.to], alternateRoute: false}, function(err, result) {      
        deferred.resolve(result);
        routes.push(result.route_geometry);
      });
      the_promises.push(deferred.promise);
    });

    return Q.all(the_promises);
  }

  function returnRoutes() {
    console.log('Inside returnRoutes()');
    return res.json(routes);
  }

  query()
    .then(function() {
      console.log('then() 1');
      return computeRoutes();
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log('then() 2');
      return returnRoutes();
    });
```

Comment: What was the problem? What did you change?